# What do people use to mount PIR sensors, cameras etc. - stand offs?

Tags: surface-mount, mount, mounting-holes, panel-mounting

Asking here because I am struggling to figure out what people use to mount their Raspberry PI modules for instance a PIR sensor or a camera.

They all come with tiny holes and I am not sure how to mount/attach these. I want to attached the PIR sensor to a piece of wood raised about 1 inch and a camera to a piece of plastic.

The motherboard I have was connected by stand offs which I thought would solve my problem but they are too big for the holes that are tiny.

https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07TP2YYQB/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Could someone point me in the right direction on what people are using to mount these tiny pieces of electronics for their projects?

I understand I could buy a 3D printer and do things like [this](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1718985) but that seems a bit overkill for what I am doing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks like a kit of M3 (3mm) standoffs and screws which are common (I've got one). The holes might be 2mm, so look for some M2 machine screws, nuts etc.

Comment: Ahh great thanks Ian so something like this should do the job https://www.amazon.co.uk/FandWay-Threaded-Internal-Assortment-Wrenches/dp/B09SH7N5PV/ref=sr_1_9

Comment: yes, but check the size of your holes first if you can.

Comment: Thanks for the M1, M2 etc tip Ian turns out I have a glasses kit with screws in I can use works for what I need.